# Load ArcGIS Server layers into web using ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Don't know what I'm doing wrong; trying to load layers from ArcGIS Server  into web using 'ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer', can see the basemap but not the layer.

see code below:

```
<html>

<head>

<
<title>FeatureLayer</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.19/esri/css/esri.css">

<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.19/"></script>




<script>
require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ],


function(
    Map,
    FeatureLayer
  )
 {





 // Add data from ArcGIS Server

var featureLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("https://herse.chelmsford.chelmsfordbc:6443/arcgis/rest/services//Boundaries/MapServer/2");




map.add(featureLayer);

  });
</script>
```

Comment: There is an extra "/" in the path for the feature layer url (.../services//Boundaries/...). Did you see any errors in your console? Also, why are you loading the FeatureLayer module but using "esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer"

Comment: Hi Kenbuja, didn't get an error. on the FeatureLayer load, what will be the best way to load a layer from ArcGIS server.

Comment: var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://herse.chelmsford.chelmsfordbc:6443/arcgis/rest/services/Boundaries/MapServer/2");

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add a Feature Layer using a `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer`, which is not the right class. Use `FeatureLayer` instead (see the example in the [ESRI Documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/layers_feature.html))

```
var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://herse.chelmsford.chelmsfordbc:6443/arcgis/rest/services//Boundaries/MapServer/2");
map.addLayer(featureLayer);
```

If you want to really add a Dynamic Map Service, instead of a Feature Layer, then [check this out](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/map_dynamic.html).

**Note:** You need first to create a `Map` object before add the feature layer to it. I think you did it, because you can see the basemap, but just in case...

Comment: Thanks Katah, I do have mybase map. I have made changes still unable to see the layer;  // layer from server.
        var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https:\\herse.chelmsford.chelmsfordbc:6443/arcgis/rest/services/Ordnance_Survey/Boundaries/MapServer/1");
        
  
        map.addLayer(featureLayer);

Comment: @MatildaAjiri Please check the following:

- 1 Try to add first a "sample" layer from ArcGIS. For example [this](https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/Landscape_Trees/FeatureServer/0). Is it working?

- 2 Check the type of your layer. For that go to your [Layer URL](https://herse.chelmsford.chelmsfordbc:6443/arc‌​gis/rest/services/Or‌​dnance_Survey/Bounda‌​ries/MapServer/1) and the fourth property should be the type. Which type of Layer do you have?